# imagecreatefrompng from outside webroot

Tags: php

So, what am doing is that.. Am uploading the image using move_uploaded_file to a folder say x outside the webroot..

```
/public_html
 .php file
/x
 .image
```

Now am loading the image using php script to let user crop it. After am done getting the coordinated now I wanna use imagecreatefrompng to copy the temp image to the final image... But it says that it unable to find the file. For doesn't exist.

> URL: imagecreatefrompng("../x/imagename.png")

And the file does exist. Well this is the path I used for readfile()...is it gonna be different for createimagefrompng() ?

P.S I m uploading the file outside the webroot for secure file upload. And there is no space in the path or file name.

It will be better if I don't have to use any frameworks.

Comment: Try with absolute, instead of relative path. You can use `__DIR__` constant to refer current directory. So it's going to be like `__DIR__."/../x/imagename.png"`

Comment: Heyy thanx....I m unable to try it right now due to some technical issues but I'll try it ASAP... Thanx!